# SQL update and increment column using a subquery from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's [my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/600de1/2). My query:

```
update foos
set foo_id = ((SELECT max_foo_id FROM (SELECT MAX(foo_id) AS max_foo_id FROM foos) AS temp_foos) + 1)
where foo_id is null;
```

produces values `1, 2, 2, 2` for foo_ids (subquery only run once?) but I'd like it to give me `1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: If foo_id is a key value, why not allow the database to provide the values.  They can do it so much better than any of us.  Oh wait a minute, it can't be a key value if you have nulls.

Comment: Yes the values in foo_id have no relation to the auto increment id column.

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

```
UPDATE  foos a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.bar_ID,
                    @rn := @rn + 1 row_Num
            FROM    foos a,(SELECT @rn := (SELECT MAX(foo_ID) FROM foos)) b
            WHERE   a.foo_ID IS NULL
        ) b ON a.bar_ID = b.bar_ID
SET     a.foo_id = b.row_Num
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3956c/1)

---

**UPDATE 1**

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with ORDER BY clause*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49a1d/1)

Comment: With this approach, if there is another thread updating the table will I run into concurrency issues? (FYI there is no relation between `id` and `foo_id` in the table.)

Comment: maybe yes, since this is session variable.